# Android + Gradle; Cannot access support-v4:23.x.x

Tags: android, gradle, support-v4

Being used to ANT for configuring Android projects in Netbeans, I am new to Android Studio and Gradle.

(In both Netbeans and Android Studio) I am struggling a bit with Gradle dependencies to the last versions of the Android support-v4 library. Everything is fine as long as version is set below 23.0.0, i.e. 22 21 etc, but when using support-v4:23.x.x, things go awry.

To investigate this problem, I have made a minimalist project consisting of one FragmentActivity only. Specifying v4 23, it cannot find any core methods of Activity or FragmentActivity, like e.g. getWindow()

I have tried both mavenCentral() and mavenLocal().

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: The build.gradle content added below.

```
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.*

   apply plugin: 'base' // To add "clean" task to the root project.

   subprojects {
       apply from: rootProject.file('common.gradle')
   }

   task mergedJavadoc(type: Javadoc, description: 'Creates Javadoc from all the projects.') {
       title = 'All modules'
       destinationDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'merged-javadoc')

       // Note: The closures below are executed lazily.
       source {
          subprojects*.sourceSets*.main*.allSource
       }   
   }

   buildscript {
       repositories {
           jcenter()
       }
       //Make sure that gradle is updated to this version
       dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
       } 
   }

   repositories {
       mavenLocal() 
       mavenCentral() //se viktig kommentar 030416  
       flatDir {dirs 'libs'}
   }

   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   ext {
       supportLibVersion = '23.2.1'
       //versionName = '2.8.0'
   }

   android {
       compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion = '23.0.3' //"21.1.2"
       //publishNonDefault true

       defaultConfig {
           //minSdkVersion 15 //Spotify requires min14, Facebook min15
           //targetSdkVersion 23
       }

       sourceSets {
           main {
               manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
               java.srcDirs = ['src']
               res.srcDirs = ['res']
           }
       }

       buildTypes {

           debug {
               applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                   variant.outputs.each { output ->
                       output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, output.outputFile.name.
                               replace(".aar", "-${versionName}.aar"))
                   }
               }
           }

       }
   }
   dependencies {
       //support
       compile ('com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1') 
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
```

}

Comment: post your build.gradle.

Comment: try this dependencies , dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
}

Comment: The support libraries are not in mavenCentral. Update your SDK Manager.

Comment: It is strange to me that Android SDK manager reports support-v4:23.2.1 as the latest revision in the library, while the m2repository actually contains also the version 23.3.0? Is the 23.2.1 the "officially latest" jar library, versus the 3.3.0 aar file in the repository?

Comment: Thanks for the comment that support libraries are not available via MavenCentral. It means this miniproject now builds in Android Studio for all versions of support-v4, as I discovered the blunder that support-v4:23.x.x was not installed on this pc that I use as a replacement pc this week.